# PageNumber - Issue with viewpageindicator library

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using viewpager for displaying 7 pages . I am also using viewpagerindicator lib to get  as no of circles as the pages are in viewpager.

When i scroll pages in viewpager I want to display user that you are in page 1 , pager 2 ... . respectively. when he scroll the pages in viewpager.

i am using getcurrentitem() of pagedapter  to get in which page i am .. But it go not give me correct result.

Is i am doing some thing wrong?
How to count exact page number in viewpager ?

I tried two ways. 
First

```
    scScreens = new Fragment[mSessionManager.getPosScreens()];
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return scScreens[position];
    }
```

In each Fragment i Wrote the page Number. So that if the respective fragment show change the page Number. (Very bad Way) I have to create 7 Classes (Maximum pages) .

Second

```
        pagestextview.setText(getCurrentItem()+1);
```

It work while scrolling first ,  but gives unexpected result when scrolling back to first

Comment: What result do you get when using getCurrentItem()? - it is actually the correct method to use in this case.

Comment: @Phil i have updated the question can you check once

Comment: ask for the position from the ViewPager. it should have the right value aswell

Comment: @bofredo i did not understand .. can you please explain little

Comment: i'll post how my ViewPager works. maybe you get some new info.

Answer (score 0):

i can recommend the FragmentStateAdapter, as it handles the creating/destroying of the fragments pretty well.

```
        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mContactList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

                    Contact mContact = mContactList.get(pos);
                    int mCurrentPosition = mContact.getPosition();
                    return ContactDetailsFragment.newInstance(mCurrentPosition);                    
            }
        });

        //loads the proper fragment on its meant-to-be position into the ViewPager
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```